# SQL tuning advice requested

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have some PL/SQL, which runs and "works" I was wondering if I can write it in a more efficient manner?

As some background, the metadata table contains information that can be used to construct queries executed on a remote database.
This is passed into "c1". "driver_table" is used to limit the data returned, we don't need all of it so there are some conditions on the query. 
It may be, for example, LIMITER_USER.TABLE1, mand_join is a join condition, e.g. A.ID = B.ID add_joins is a where clause. E.g. B.DTE >= '01-DEC-2014'
So, ultimately, the PL/SQL constructs a number of SQL's in a loop and outputs them in the output.

```
declare
v_sql_c1 pls_integer;
l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';

begin

for c1 in (select /*+parallel*/ * from meta_data_tbl where add_joins is not null)
loop
execute immediate' select /*+parallel*/ count(*) from '||c1.schema||'.'||c1.table|| '@' ||l_dblink ||' b '
||','||
c1.driver_table 
|| '@' ||l_dblink ||' a '
||' where '||
c1.mand_join
||' and '||
c1.add_joins
into v_sql_c1;
dbms_output.put_line(v_sql_c1);
end loop;
end;
/
```

I'd like the output to be produced as efficiently as possible, if it isn't being already. Currently it takes twelve minutes to complete

Comment: Without having access to your database, your data, and (apparently) the other databases you want your dynamic queries to access there's really not much anyone here can do. Nor do we have any idea of how many queries you're actually executing here.

Comment: Ok Bob - thanks. I do realise that there are some things out of scope, but I was thinking more along the lines of PL/SQL objects I could use instead, or other objects like views, bulk collects, the parallelism I'm using... things "like" that which are perhaps unbeknown to me but present efficiencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a parallel pipelined function to enable both concurrency and parallelism.

The terms "concurrency" and "parallelism" are often synonymous, but in Oracle they have sometimes different meanings.  Concurrency is when multiple SQL statements or PL/SQL blocks are run at the same time, and parallelism is when a single SQL statement is run with many threads.

Your current program uses parallelism to get the cursor data, but that does not make the cursor FOR loop run in multiple threads.  Since you're using database links, I assume these statements will run on many databases, so you can probably save time by running them on multiple databases at the same time.

The parallel pipelined function runs the input cursor in parallel, and partitions the results and runs them in multiple threads.  (You can achieve the same thing using DBMS_SCHEDULER, but that solution requires more management code.)

```
--Create parallel pipelined function.
create or replace function parallel_pipe(p_cursor sys_refcursor)
return sys.odcinumberlist pipelined
parallel_enable(partition p_cursor by any) is
    v_meta_data_tbl meta_data_tbl%rowtype;
    v_sql varchar2(32767);
    v_count number;
begin
    loop
        fetch p_cursor into v_meta_data_tbl;
        exit when p_cursor%notfound;

        v_sql := 'select /*+ parallel */ count(*) from '||
            v_meta_data_tbl.schema||'.'||v_meta_data_tbl.table_name;

        execute immediate v_sql into v_count;

        pipe row(v_count);
    end loop;
end;
/

--Call the function.
select column_value row_count
from table(parallel_pipe(cursor(select /*+ parallel */ * from meta_data_tbl)));
```

I didn't recreate your entire table and join.  I just used a schema small enough to demonstrate the principles:

```
create table meta_data_tbl(schema varchar2(128), table_name varchar2(128));
insert into meta_data_tbl select 'SYS', 'DUAL' from dual connect by level <= 100;
commit;
```

Be careful when combining concurrency and parallelism.  The above solution could make your servers work orders of magnitude harder.  You should experiment with different combinations - try running only concurrency, or concurrency plus small amounts of parallelism, etc.

Comment: Hmm. Jon, I'm receiving the following error. Any ideas?

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P000
ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back
ORA-06512: at "USER1.PARALLEL_PIPE", line 22

Comment: I think it's something to do with the db_link

Comment: @Dave Woops, I forgot to remove some of my debugging code.  I got rid of the `pragma autonoumous_transaction`, which is only necessary if data is changed.  Try it again and let me know if it still doesn't work.